# Why is my output Undefined or NaN?

Tags: javascript

For some reason, when I enter value, all of the output is
undefined and NaN and I have no idea why.I think the
error is really simple..so simple I would facepalm. Sorry 
for my code, I'm still new to javascript. And also, nevermind about the Credit Card.

```
function processAmount(){ 
    var numOfLiters= parseInt(document.estore.noOfLiters.value);
    var result;
    var perLiterAmount;
    var gasType;

    switch(gasType){
    case "Premium": 

            perLiterAmount= 50;
            result= 50*numOfLiters;
            break;
    case "Diesel":
           perLiterAmount= 38;
          result= 38*numOfLiters;
            break;

    case "Unleaded":
           perLiterAmount= 44;
            result= 44*numOfLiters;
            break;
    }



    var vat= result*0.12;

    document.write("<p>Fuel Type: " + gasType + "</p>");
    document.write("<p>Price per Liter amount: " + perLiterAmount + "</p>");
    document.write("<p>Purchase Amount: " + result + "</p>");
    document.write("<p>VAT: " + vat + "</p>");
    document.write("<p>TOTAL AMOUNT: " + (result+vat) + "</p>");
    document.write("<p>Credit Card : " + creditCard + "</p>");`
```

and here is the form:

```
 <form name='estore' id='estore'>
   <fieldset>
            <legend>Gasoline eStore</legend>
                <p>Enter gasoline type:
                    <select name='gastype' id='gastype'>
                        <option value="Premium"> Premium</option>
                        <option value="Unleaded"> Unleaded</option>
                        <option value="Diesel"> Diesel</option>
                        </select></p>

                <p> Enter number of Liters:
                    <input type='number' name='noOfLiters' id='noOfLiters'/>
                </p>

                <p> Enter Credit Card Number:
                    <input type="number" name='creditCardNumber' id='creditCardNumber'/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type='button' value='Submit' 
                        onclick="processAmount()"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type='reset'/>
                </p>
```

Comment: What is gasType ?

Comment: Because your `gasType` is not initialised .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace

```
var gasType;
```

with

```
var gasType = document.getElementById('gastype').value;
```

That way your method `processAmount()` should work as intended.
As some other replies here already suggested, you didn't initialize your variable  `gasType`, so it was `undefined`.

Using the line above, you initialize it with the value from the `select` field.

Answer (score 2):

First assign the value to `gasType` and then put it in `switch` case.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your function assign the value to `gastype`

```
var gastype = $('#gastype :selected').val();
```

Comment: This would require the author to use jQuery but it doesn't look like that from their code. So, author, if you want to use this code, make sure your project includes jQuery as a dependency.